# Change A-Record in Hetzner Konsoleh

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I am a Hetzner level 19 shared hosting client and would like to change the A-record for my domain. When I log in to konsoleh, I see which IP-address it points to at the moment, but not where I can change it.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you reviewed the [support documentation](http://www.hetzner.co.za/helpcentre/index.php/articles/content/category/the_domain_name_system/how_do_i_manage_my_d_473/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called Hetzner support. It was because I had to log in with my client id, not with my domain. Then I could just click on the A-record and edit it.